# unable to yarn install in ubuntu(fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module)

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, fsevents

I cloned a project from Github and following the initial instructions, it shows this error described below.

I tried to understand it and google it, and from there I changed my NodeJS version multiple times using `nvm` but the problem is not resolved, the error is not getting fixed.

```
info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this 
module.
info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed 
compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
error get-caller-file@2.0.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with 
this module. Expected version "6.* || 8.* || >= 10.*".
error An unexpected error occurred: "Found incompatible module".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the 
information provided in "/home/ongraph/Desktop/node/my- 
business/frontend/shared/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation 
about this command.
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: sh
Arguments: -c cd frontend/shared && yarn install
Directory: /home/ongraph/Desktop/node/my-business
Output:
".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the 
information provided in 
"/home/ongraph/Desktop/node/my-business/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation 
about this command.
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: sh
Arguments: -c yarn install && yarn install-backend &&
yarn install-shared && yarn install-web && yarn install-native
Directory: /home/ongraph/Desktop/node/my-business
Output:
".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the 
information provided in "/home/ongraph/Desktop/node/my- 
business/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation 
about this command.
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: sh
Arguments: -c yarn install-all && yarn knex migrate:latest && yarn 
generate-schema --ignore-engines
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the wrong thing :) `fsevents` is optional and you don't need to worry about it. Instead focus on this one:

```
error get-caller-file@2.0.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this 
module. Expected version "6.* || 8.* || >= 10.*". error An unexpected 
error occurred: "Found incompatible module".
```

The error is pretty descriptive. Please install the correct node version and you're good to go! If you have trouble with conflicting node versions (in case you're working on several projects with separate requirements), head over to: https://github.com/creationix/nvm and install nvm in order to manage multiple node installations in parallel.

Comment: Nvm is great. Makes life a lot easier and should honestly be the default way developers set up node.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i am already using nvm and installed 8.x, 9.x, 10.x, 11.x and tried with every version but again the error is the same

Comment: Did you delete folders and lockfiles after the version change? Also if you're in a different shell the node version might get reset by nvm.